# How to get array of objects in javascript from an array of dictionaries in python?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, plotly-dash, custom-component

I'm trying to use an array of dictionaries in python as arguement to a custom dash component and use it as array of objects

in python :

```
audioList_py = [
    {
        "name": "random",
        "singer": 'waveGAN\'s music',
        "cover":
          'link_1.jpg',
        "musicSrc":
          'link_1.mp3',
    },
    {
        "name": "random",
        "singer": 'waveGAN\'s music',
        "cover":
          'link_2.jpg',
        "musicSrc":
          'link_2.mp3',
    },

 ... etc
]
```

in Javascript:

```
audioList1_js = [
        {
            name: "random",
            singer: 'waveGAN\'s music',
            cover:'link_1.jpg',
            musicSrc: 'link_1.mp3',
        },
        {
            name: "random",
            singer: 'waveGAN\'s music',
            cover: 'link_2.jpg',
            musicSrc: 'link_2.mp3',
        },

     ... etc
    ]
```

Here is snippet of javascript code of the dash custom component:

```
export default class MusicComponent extends Component {
    render() {
      const {id, audioLists} = this.props;
        return (
            <div>
                <h1>{id}</h1>
                <ReactJkMusicPlayer audioLists={audio_list}/>,
            </div>
        );
    }
}

MusicComponent.defaultProps = {};

MusicComponent.propTypes = {
    /**
     * The ID used to identify this component in Dash callbacks.
     */
    audios: PropTypes.array,
    id: PropTypes.string,

};
```

And using the generated component in python:

```
app = dash.Dash(__name__)
app.layout = html.Div([
    music_component.MusicComponent(audios=audioList_py),
    html.Div(id='output'),
    ... etc
])
```

But I got :

```
TypeError: The `music_component.MusicComponent` component (version 0.0.1) received an unexpected keyword argument: `audios`Allowed arguments: id
```

What I am doing wrong ?

Any help or advice will be appreciated, Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure you run `npm run build` after you make a change to your custom React component. With those proptypes you shouldn't get that error. If I remove the `audios` proptype I can reproduce that error.

Besides that you pass a value to the `audios` property:

```
music_component.MusicComponent(audios=audioList_py)
```

but you try to retrieve `audioLists` from props:

```
const {id, audioLists} = this.props;
```

Change this to:

```
const {id, audios} = this.props;
```

Demo

```
export default class MusicComponent extends Component {
    render() {
        const {id, audios} = this.props;
        return (
            <div>
                <h1>{id}</h1>
                <ReactJkMusicPlayer audioLists={audios} />
            </div>
        );
    }
}

MusicComponent.defaultProps = {};

MusicComponent.propTypes = {
    /**
     * The ID used to identify this component in Dash callbacks.
     */
    id: PropTypes.string,

    audios: PropTypes.array,
};
```

Comment: Thank you man, the issue is resolved ! I should run `npm run build:backends`.

Answer (score 0):

Issue fixed, I should run : `npm run build:backends` to generate the Python, R and Julia class files for the components, but instead I was executing `npm run build:js` and this command just generate the JavaScript bundle (which didn't know about the new props).

And set the audios property in the component to be like so:

```
MusicComponent.defaultProps = {audios: audioList1};

MusicComponent.propTypes = {
    id: PropTypes.string,
    audios: PropTypes.arrayOf(PropTypes.objectOf(PropTypes.string)).isRequired
};
```

Comment: `npm run build` works also, because `npm run build` runs `npm run build:js && npm run build:backends`.

Comment: Unfortunately, It didn't for me. from package.json:  `"build:js": "webpack --mode production"` , and `"build:backends": "dash-generate-components ./src/lib/components music_component -p package-info.json --r-prefix '' --jl-prefix ''"`, thank you again for the quick reaction.

Comment: My bad I was executing:  `build:js` not `build` 